# Multiple Correspondence Analysis to inform a composite variable

Tags: categorical-data, correspondence-analysis

I have 28 categorical variables, some binary, some with many levels (n=161).

I want to use some of these variables to make a composite variable to investigate a latent characteristic, and then test the association of this characteristic with the remaining variables in the dataset.

My plan is to use MCA and use the variables suggested by one of the dimensions to make a composite variable, check this for consistency using Cronbach or similar and then model the composite using log-linear analysis or logistic regression.

Can anyone tell me if this is a misuse of MCA? I wouldn't be using the dimension itself, just taking the variables associated with the dimension and using them in subsequent analysis. All comments welcome. (I don't think I need to submit a sample dataset here as its a theory question?)

Comment: Like in PCA, MCA produces dimensions which can be understood as "latent" characteristics. The coordinates (the scores) are linear combinations of the input variables (of their categories). If you don't like the weights in those combinations you are in the right to derive other weights by a subsequent analysis you feel appropriate. So, generally, I see no missuse of MCA so far.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't see a way to vote for this.